# Winter Bash icon makes top bar blink and reflow

Tags: bug, winter-bash

Winter Bash is back. I don't know why it happens, but it would appear that the icon in the top bar is only rendered *after* the ~250 ms costing call to `https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/api/current-hats?callback=...`.

This makes the icon in the top bar blink (and probably reflow, but not sure if that's the cause) for a few weeks per year, on every page view.

Can a little love be spent on optimizing this? It's pretty annoying.

Comment: doesn't seem to happen for me, possibly related to me making the top bar not sticky? The icon does show up late, but no reflow/blink occurs. (would be hilarious if this only happens for users who haven't disabled sticky)

Comment: I see. I don't get the reflow because i removed the useless icon on the right